# htaccess rename file to $_GET php variable

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a page which currently displays user information based on values passed through `$_GET['username']`

What I currently have Is when a user goes to `url.com/user/index?username=username` (for example) it will display username's page.
If the variable is not set however like `url.com/user/index`, it will display the logged in users page instead.

It works, however, that Is not what I want. How I would like it to work is; if the user goes to `url.com/user/exampleuser` it will display exampleuser's page and If they go to `url.com/user/` it just displays the logged in user.

I am currently testing on an xampp server (localhost) and I can't seem to find anything which works how I would like it to.

Any and all help is appreciated!

**EDIT**

this is my new .htaccess:

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^user/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ user/index?username=$1;
```

however, when I go to the page i.e. `localhost/test/user/username` it gives me `object not found!` error

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^user/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ user/index?username=$1; 
# for particular user details

RewriteRule ^user/$ user/index; # for all logged in user list
```

For Eg. your url is `user/index?username=testuser` after rewrite apply it look like `user/testuser` it is for particular user details for all user list you just use `user/`

Comment: hi, I have added this code to my htaccess file, however, I get the error `Object not found!` when I go to a link; for example: `localhost/test/user/username`.. please check edit

Comment: check your php.ini file is your mode rewrite is enable or not  find httpd.conf file {xampp_dir}/apache/conf/httpd.conf
{wamp_dir}/apache/conf/httpd.conf and then

Comment: find #LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so and remove the ‘#’ sign.